# Add datepicker on fullScreen

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to add a datepicker to `input` on `rangeSelector` also on fullScreen mode. I'm trying to use the condition property with callback function, but I couldn't find anything about the `Highcharts.ResponsiveCallbackFunction` to help me achieve this. Is there any workaround?

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/bernardo0marques/ebxLkq8u/8/) is my attemp

```js
rules: [
  {
    callback: function() {
      console.log('UNDER RULES');
      return false;
    },
    condition: {
      callback: function() {
        if (this.fullscreen.isOpen){
          setTimeout(function() {
            $('input.highcharts-range-selector', $('#' + chart.options.chart.renderTo)).datepicker()
          }, 0)
          return true
        }
        console.log('UNDER CONDITION');
        return false;
      }
    },
  }
]
```

Also sometimes during debugging it seems like condition loop is running multiple times, I don't know if this is an expected behavior or if I'm using it the wrong way. Sometimes if I use too many `console.log` I get an error `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.`

Comment: I did many tries to achieve it but without the result... To understand the problem open your developer console and check in the elements tree that inside the `container` Highcharts render and inner one and the current full-screen implementation resize only the nested div, meanwhile the date picker lefts outside. I tried to attach the datepicker to the inner div, but it doesn't work - I don't know why. My attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lucb20nz/

Comment: Is your link correct? It seems that not even the outer datepicker is working, and I couldn't find anything trying to attach it to inner div

Comment: unfortunately not - it is my attempt to attach datepicker to the inner chart container (which is visible in the fullscreen mode), but I can't debug why the datepicker is not applying for this container.